# airflow helm chart: How to use a custom docker image from a private registry?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

In our company we have a private docker registry (artifactory) and need to use it to store our docker images.

So, if I want to use custom airflow docker image (par example, with some extra pip and apt packages installed) I should save this image in our private docker registry.

Can anybody tell me, how can I order `airflow`'s helm chart to pull image from private docker registry? And how to pass credentials in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [this one](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts). You can edit the [image field](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/420eae29c454f6e7e6a7837706ca2e6c0fe792b8/charts/airflow/values.yaml#L12) in the values and apply it like that:

```
helm install airflow -f values airflow-stable/airflow
```

or directly by setting the option from command line:

```
helm install airflow airflow-stable/airflow --set airflow.image.repository=custom-image-address
```

For credentials, there is  [pullSecret](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/420eae29c454f6e7e6a7837706ca2e6c0fe792b8/charts/airflow/values.yaml#L15)

```
pullSecret: ""
```

you can edit this to point docker secret for your registry.
[Check this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/).
Also you can set this option from the command line like the previous example.